Do you have auto-completion problem when inserting a callout block within your quarto doc?
When I'm using Quarto doc within Rstudio I have some problem with auto-completion. After running some tests I isolated the problem. When I'm inserting a callout bloc my auto-completion (with tab) just don't work anymore. With this simple code I can open the column menu with tab after putting a $ after tmp in the first bloc but when I'm doing it for the second code block I cannot open the menu.
I use the minimal quarto doc header :
title: "Untitled"

format: html

editor: visual

And then short piece of code. 

```{r}

    mtcars
    tmp = data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
    tmp

```

::: callout-important

blablabla

:::

```{r}

    tmp

```

Do you have similar problems ? can someone just try to reproduce the problem and tell me if it's me or a real bug ? I'm using "R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)", "Rstudio Chocolate Cosmos 2024.04.0 Build 735" and "Quarto 1.2.280"
What I have tried
I have uninstalled and reinstalled R and Rstudio, and the problem do not depend on package loading, I have the same problem whether I'm doing in a new session with nothing loaded or in a session with my working packages.
